# Javascript adding variable twice

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var m = 0;
function addmoney(){
    var today = new Date();
    var s =today.getSeconds();
    if(s == 30){
        m += 10;
    }
    document.getElementById('mon').innerHTML=s+" money: "+m;
    t=setTimeout(function(){addmoney()},500);
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is to add 10 to the value of m every 30 seconds. The problem here is that the variable was actually being added twice. I was wondering why this was the case?

EDIT: Sorry did not mean to do s++, eitherways it did not change much.

Comment: FYI, `setTimeout(function(){addmoney()},500)` is simpler written as `setTimeout(addmoney,500)`

Comment: when and how do you call `addmoney()` for the first time?

Comment: You set your timeout function to call after 0.5 seconds. getSeconds() only returns full seconds. So if you call the function at e.g. 12:30:01 100ms which returns 30sec and the next call resolves fast enough the next date could be 12:30:01 700ms which also returns 30sec m gets increased twice at this point of time...to be on the safe side, set timeout to 1000ms ;)

Comment: @Igle Thanks for the explanation, I was wondering what was wrong with it. The timeout trick you gave me definitely also fixed the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

```
var m = 0,
    mon = document.getElementById('mon');

var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
  m += 10;
  mon.innerHTML = "money: " + m;
}, 30000);
```

If for whatever reason you would like to stop adding money, you can use [window.clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

```
// stop collecting monies!
clearInterval(interval);
```

---

[Here's a jsbin.com demo](http://jsbin.com/EDOxUJes/1/edit)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I will accept the answer once I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

Add a small change to it

```
if(s == 30 || s == 0)
```

This is because in the system the seconds counter gets reset to 0 after it crosses 60

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that variable  `s` is being rewritten in time intervals of 500ms (so the `s++` trick does not work). Either increase the interval or use a global variable to store the last time.